# Implementing tail recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, tail-recursion

I've written a simple function in haskell that is non tail recursive that sums up the values inside a list where:

```
nonTailRecursiveSum :: [Integer] -> Integer
nonTailRecursiveSum [] = 0 --base case
nonTailRecursiveSum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
```

But what I'm trying to do now is to implement the same function but using tail recursion. For what i know, tail recursion performs the recursive call at the final step so i tried something like:

```
tailRecursiveSum :: [Integer] -> Integer
tailRecursiveSum [] = 0
tailRecursiveSum (x:xs) = aux_f(x) + tailRecursiveSum xs
.
.
```

But i got lost in the midway as I'm not familiar with tail recursion in Haskell. Could anyone assist me on the continuation of the tail recursive version of the code?

Comment: `sum (x:xs) = aux xs x`  where `aux (x:xs) total = aux xs (x + total)`

Comment: For the recursion to be tail recursion, you need your cases to be similar to `tailRecursiveFunction something = tailRecursiveFunction somethingElse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing with it for a bit,

```
sum (x:y:xs) = x + sum (y:xs)
             = x + (y + sum xs)
             = (x + y) + sum xs

g a b = a + sum b

sum (x:y:xs) = g x (y:xs)
             = x + g y xs
             = g (x+y) xs   -- !!!
```

the last one is in tail recursive form! We thus just define

```
sum xs = g 0 xs
  where
  g acc [] = ...
  g acc (x:xs) = g (acc + ...) ...
```

Fill in the blanks!

Comment: You can start with `sum (x:xs) = g x xs` immediately to avoid `0 + ...`. (Which only works because `(+) 0` is essentially `id` for numeric types.)

Comment: but then I have to handle the `[]` case separately. With the explicit `0`. It's unavoidable.

Comment: What do you mean by the last one (of the first code block) being in tail recursive form?

Comment: @DavidYoung in `g x (y:xs) = g (x+y) xs`, call to `g` is a tail call.